# sprintf in PHP push notification

Tags: php, printf

Im using PHP to send notificationa to subscribed users when certain values are present in a database -

The Format I'm using is

```
'body' => sprintf(trim($event['deviceName']) . ' went to ' . trim($event['deviceStatus']) . ' mode %s' .trim($event['deviceMessage']), date('H:i')),
```

And the result:

```
Alarm One went to Activated mode 15:30 User Set
```

I have tried %c \n \v \r in multiple variations and positions - using double quotes etc - I can't seem to format the message to display as:

```
Alarm One went to Activated Mode at 15:30
User Set
```

with the 'deviceMessage' on a new line -
on Windows using the \n puts it on a new line but displays \n in the push notification - on Android it just adds \n to the string

Comment: You can use [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). It works fine with `sprintf`.

Comment: I've tried a few variations of <<<EOT       EOT can't seem to get it working

Comment: \n is literal, not a new line character, inside of single quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Using external variables inside the format parameter of `sprintf`  is a ***very bad idea***. Rewrite your code like this, it contains `\r\n` inside double quotes:

```
sprintf("%s went to %s mode %s\r\n%s",
    trim($event['deviceName']),
    trim($event['deviceStatus']),
    date('H:i'),
    trim($event['deviceMessage'])
);
```

Comment: I've tried this - great information, it must be android that stops the formatting